# PrivateKey not invalidated on enrollment

Tags: android, private-key, android-fingerprint-api

have you experienced the case when Android Fingerprint APIs are behaving in the not expected way? The issue I have is when I generate `PrivateKey` with given `attestationChallenge` and `userAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` for data signing. Everything works as expected if I don't enroll new fingerprints however after enrollment of a new fingerprint I expect for that key to be permanently invalidated but this is not the case. Have you experienced the similar?

Below is the code I'm using to generate the `PrivateKey`.

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeystore")
keyStore.load(null)
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm, "AndroidKeyStore")
val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("alias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
builder.apply {
    setDigests(digests)
    setSignaturePaddings(paddings)
    setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
    setAttestationChallenge(attestationChallenge)
    setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(userAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds)
}

keyPairGenerator.initialize(builder.build())
keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. `PrivateKey` will not be invalidated by OS if `userAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` is set to a positive value. The key will only be invalidated on the enrolment of new fingerprint if its purpose is to be used only when authenticated with fingerprint.